# Azure MySQL IOPS will not go below 400

Tags: mysql, azure, iops

I am using Azure MySQL database, the tier is burstable (1-2 vCores), standard B1s, but the IOPS will not go below 400, which is supposed to be the max.

Comment: What queries are you running?  Perhaps they can be made more efficient -- possibly by adding a composite index.

Comment: thank you @RickJames , will look into that